# Angular material autocomplete: How to prevent valuechange on option selection

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete, observable

I have a form field connected to an autocomplete. The markup code looks like this:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>{{'label.descrizione'|translate}}</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="{{'label.descrizione'|translate}}" formControlName="descrizione" required
    [matAutocomplete]="suggestionsAutocomplete">
  <mat-autocomplete #suggestionsAutocomplete>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestion of this.suggestions" [value]="suggestion.value"
      (click)="suggestionSelected(suggestion)">
      {{suggestion.value}} <span class="mat-small">{{suggestion.descrizioneCategoria}}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <mat-error *ngIf="editFG.get('descrizione')?.invalid">{{'validations.required' | translate}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

The autocomplete options are fed in the code that follows. The idea is that while the user is typing, a server request is sent to get the option to be displayed.

```js
// connect suggestions
this.editFG.get('descrizione')?.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  filter(value => value.length >= 3),
  switchMap((term: string) => this.operazioni.getSuggestions(TipoOperazione.CASH, this.editFG.get('currency')?.value, term))
).subscribe(suggestions => {
  console.log("Fired value change")
  // console.dir(suggestions)
  this.suggestions = suggestions;
});
```

The idea here is, every time the user wrote more than 3 chars, but not more frequently than 300ms, the options are "re-updated" based on the typed term.

It works perfectly, but with one drawback. Once the user selects a value in the options, the valuechange emits another event, that triggers another - useless - server call, and I would like to prevent it.
What happens in the selection callback occurs later, and so far the callback is empty.
**Is there a way to filter out that event, and just that?**

Comment: Would be great if you could provide a Stackblitz for this as I'm not really sure why selecting an option should impact the value of `get('descrizione')`. Identifying why this is will likely help you resolve the issue. If there is no way around the additional event emission, `skipWhile` or an additional `filter` will allow you to ignore those events provided there is a way to differentiate from a normal typed input (e.g. if the value emitted is `null` instead of a string)

Comment: Apparently it's the native behaviour of the mat-form-field. I'll investigate more and try to link the stackblitz as soon as I can. As soon one of the option is selected, the form control is updated with the value from the option. This produces a valuechanges event that is the one I don't want. All this happens before any of my handlers is triggered.

Comment: Hope you figured out the solution. If you didn't here is how to do it:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14893

Basically as you type, the valuechanges fires with a string object (the text you are typing), but when u select the option you get an object instead. So filter using typeof to determine if the valuechanges object is a string or not.

Comment: @BoomDizzle I'm reading it only now, thank you! I'll investigate asap (actually that project is closed, in production, with the problem)

Comment: @angelodelia Did that work for you?